# How to make specific cells in gridview readonly where the entire row is set to editable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

This gridview shows dates of a month. Some dates are public holidays and some are weekends. Certain other days may have its own condition which it may need to be non-editable.

All these DataRows in this gridview is set to enable editing. So how can I make specific cell to be non-editable or rather read/only?

[I read this post, but it only talks about part of the solution I need.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/629107)

Comment: That post seems to give you everything you need. What are you missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enabling and disabling a cell in a Datagridview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/629107/enabling-and-disabling-a-cell-in-a-datagridview)

Comment: Can you show the structure of your gridview... Like is it accommodating all days in single row or is it weekly calendar.

Comment: Ya I am the train n on mob. I will do so when I get home. But if you *may* look at my recent questions on gridview, there are pictures of the gridview I am tackling. @meHow if your choice of duplicate could solve my issue I wouldn't really have posted this. I am being insulted ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24675684/1389394