# Casting a custom datagridview cell to its type not working

Tags: c#, datagridview, casting

I've made a custom datagridview column and cell for the purpose of disabling or hiding their controls.

```
public class DataGridViewDisableTextBoxColumn : DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
{
    private bool _textBoxesEnabled = true;
    public bool TextBoxesEnabled
    {
        get
        {
            return _textBoxesEnabled;
        }
        set
        {
            _textBoxesEnabled = value;
            if (this.DataGridView == null) return;
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.DataGridView.Rows)
            {
                var cell = row.Cells[this.Index] as DataGridViewDisableTextBoxCell;
                if (cell == null) continue;
                cell.Enabled = _textBoxesEnabled;
            }
        }
    }

    private bool _TextBoxesVisible = true;
    public bool TextBoxesVisible
    {
        get
        {
            return _TextBoxesVisible;
        }
        set
        {
            _TextBoxesVisible = value;
            if (this.DataGridView == null) return;
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.DataGridView.Rows)
            {
                var cell = row.Cells[this.Index] as DataGridViewDisableTextBoxCell;
                if (cell == null) continue;
                cell.TextBoxVisible = _TextBoxesVisible;
            }
        }
    }

    public DataGridViewDisableTextBoxColumn()
    {
        this.CellTemplate = new DataGridViewDisableTextBoxCell();
    }
}

public class DataGridViewDisableTextBoxCell : DataGridViewTextBoxCell
{
    private bool _textBoxVisibleValue;
    public bool TextBoxVisible
    {
        get
        {
            var colEnabled = true;
            if (this.OwningColumn != null) colEnabled = ((DataGridViewDisableTextBoxColumn)this.OwningColumn).TextBoxesVisible;
            return _textBoxVisibleValue && colEnabled;
        }
        set
        {
            _textBoxVisibleValue = value;
        }
    }

    private bool enabledValue;
    public bool Enabled
    {
        get
        {
            var colVisible = true;
            if (this.OwningColumn != null) colVisible = ((DataGridViewDisableTextBoxColumn)this.OwningColumn).TextBoxesEnabled;
            return enabledValue && colVisible;
        }
        set
        {
            enabledValue = value;
        }
    }

    // Override the Clone method so that the Enabled property is copied.
    public override object Clone()
    {
        DataGridViewDisableTextBoxCell cell =
            (DataGridViewDisableTextBoxCell)base.Clone();
        cell.Enabled = this.Enabled;
        cell.TextBoxVisible = this.TextBoxVisible;
        return cell;
    }

    // By default, enable the cell.
    public DataGridViewDisableTextBoxCell()
    {
        this.enabledValue = true;
        this._textBoxVisibleValue = true;
    }

    protected override void Paint(Graphics graphics,
        Rectangle clipBounds, Rectangle cellBounds, int rowIndex,
        DataGridViewElementStates elementState, object value,
        object formattedValue, string errorText,
        DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle,
        DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle advancedBorderStyle,
        DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts)
    {
        if (!this.Enabled || !this.TextBoxVisible)
        {
            // Draw the cell background, if specified.
            if ((paintParts & DataGridViewPaintParts.Background) == DataGridViewPaintParts.Background)
            {
                SolidBrush cellBackground = new SolidBrush(cellStyle.BackColor);
                graphics.FillRectangle(cellBackground, cellBounds);
                cellBackground.Dispose();
            }

            // Draw the cell borders, if specified.
            if ((paintParts & DataGridViewPaintParts.Border) == DataGridViewPaintParts.Border)
            {
                PaintBorder(graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds, cellStyle,
                    advancedBorderStyle);
            }
            if (this.TextBoxVisible && !this.Enabled)
            {
                // Draw the disabled textbox.                    
                TextBoxRenderer.DrawTextBox(graphics, cellBounds, TextBoxState.Disabled);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // The button cell is enabled, so let the base class 
            // handle the painting.
            base.Paint(graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds, rowIndex,
                elementState, value, formattedValue, errorText,
                cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle, paintParts);
        }
    }
}
```

When using the TextBoxesEnabled property on the column, this approach seems to work fine. However, if I try to do this:

```
private void gridPins_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
var row = gridPins.Rows[e.RowIndex];
var view = row.DataBoundItem as ECUTemplatePin_View;
var cellFontSize = row.Cells[colFontSize.Index] as DataGridViewDisableTextBoxCell;
cellFontSize.Enabled = view.IncludeInPrint;
}
```

The cellFontSize variable is null. It seems (from debugging) that the colFontSize is actually a standard datagridview textbox cell when my application is running, rather than the custom type, even though it it initialized as the custom type (in the .Designer.cs file)

Any suggestions where to start looking for my mistake would be greatly appreciated :)

EDIT: The colFontSize is defined as such:

```
private DataGridViewDisableTextBoxColumn colFontSize;
this.colFontSize = new DataGridViewDisableTextBoxColumn();
// 
// colFontSize
// 
this.colFontSize.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
this.colFontSize.DataPropertyName = "FontSize";
this.colFontSize.HeaderText = "Skriftstørrelse";
this.colFontSize.Name = "colFontSize";
this.colFontSize.TextBoxesEnabled = true;
this.colFontSize.TextBoxesVisible = true;
this.colFontSize.Width = 95;
```

Comment: The code you posted is incomplete… where is `colFontSize` and `view` defined?  In Addition, what exactly are you trying to do in the `CellEndEdit` event?

Comment: colFontSize is defined in the designer.cs file, view is a class I use to bind the data to my grid. Basically I'm trying to have some cells disabled if one specific property is not true on the databound object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up on this approach and used the solution from this post:

[Enabling and disabling a cell in a Datagridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629107/enabling-and-disabling-a-cell-in-a-datagridview)